# How to make continuous plots with line/block separations in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have melted data frame contains  `Msrt_Order`, `Sample_Intensity`, `rtc`, `Group` and `Msrt_Day`.

I want to make a plot of Sample Intensity peak along the Msrt_Order (measurement order, from 1 to 1000+)

```
ggplot(peak) +  geom_jitter(aes(x = Msrt_Order, y = Sample_Intensity, color = rtc, shape=rtc), alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

I want to make it better by separating them according to the msrt_Day (measurement_day, an order along with Msrt_Order, but instead of 1000+ factors, there are only 24 days as we measure 40+ samples per day.)

What I DON'T want is this

```
ggplot(peak) +  geom_jitter(aes(x = Msrt_Order, y = Sample_Intensity, color = Msrt_Day, shape=rtc), alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

because there are 24 of them, it's hard to distinguish, nor do I want 24 icons in the legend.

I tried to use `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(peak) +  geom_jitter(aes(x = Msrt_Order, y = Sample_Intensity, color = rtc, shape=rtc), alpha = 0.6) + facet_grid(~Msrt_Day)
```

[image]
But it's NOT what I expected, I want to have a continuous plot with 24 blocks separated by Mrst_Day while maintaining the Msrt_Order.

Hope you guys get my idea...

The peak csv link is here [peak.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HiiyU7oOGcT9tc1VqMqMqAoddP3-YDHv)

Comment: Please make this question reproducible by including the data in `peak` (or a representative sample of it), in a plain text format. You can use `dput()` or paste a data frame indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, please see the updated link.

Comment: If you free up your x axis it looks nicer - is this what you're after? `facet_grid(~Msrt_Day, scales = "free_x")`

Comment: unfortunatly not, maybe I didn't describe properly by using facet. I just want to maintain the x axis, same order (Msrt_Order), but split the plot by Msrt_Day. Also, if separation vertical line could help also is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is add one or more variables which describe the boundaries of `Msrt_Day` using the x-axis values `Msrt_Order`.

Here's one attempt: group by `Msrt_Day` and define the boundary as the maximum value of `Msrt_Order` for each group. Then you can use that value for `geom_vline`.

```
peak %>% 
  group_by(Msrt_Day) %>% 
  mutate(orderMax = max(Msrt_Order) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Msrt_Order, Sample_Intensity)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = rtc)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = orderMax)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a million!

Comment: Just curiosity, so basically I assume that it's very hard to plot like a facet? Or the only solution is using for loop for every Msrt_Day and arrange them in columns?

Comment: Facets are for splitting data by group. If the x-axis variable spans groups then a facet axis can only contain the range of x values, or the range specific to the facet if `scales = "free_x"` is used. So facets are not appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: Got it, I also changed the title accordingly, so the only way to make blocks is by spliting then into isolated dataframe by Msrt_Day and do for loop?